# Add a contact form to an existing contact page view using class based views in Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I'm trying to add a "contact us" form to my existing "contact us" page using a model form and class based views.
First I've created the model below:

```
class ContactUsForm(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=False)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=False, null=False)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=False, null=False)
    message_body = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subject
```

Then I've created my form in forms.py as below:

```
class ContactForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ContactUsForm
        fields = "__all__"
```

My previously existing contact page view is as below:

```
class ContactUsPageView(ListView):
    """
    In this view we are fetching site data from database, in a function named
    get_context_data. In this function, we filter the model for objects that contains
    the word 'تماس', therefore fetching data referring to the about page only.
    After that the context list is sent to the template, and there with a for loop
    and an if statement, each key, value set is chosen for the proper place.
    """

    model = SiteDataKeyValue
    template_name: str = "core/contact-us.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ContactUsPageView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["contact_page_data"] = self.model.objects.filter(key__icontains="تماس")
        return context
```

Now, I have no idea how to proceed. How am I supposed to add this form to my view, then send it along with the `contact_page_data` to the template, and how to style it (styling is not the question here and I'll deal with it as soon as the view is complete.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See whether this helps

```
class ContactUsPageView(ListView):

    model = SiteDataKeyValue
    template_name: str = "core/contact-us.html"
    context_object_name = 'contact_page_data'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return SiteDataKeyValue.objects.filter(key__icontains="تماس")

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        form = ContactForm()
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if not kwargs.get("form"):
            context['form'] = form
        return context

    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
        data = request.POST
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        # form = ContactForm(request.POST, request.FILES) # If your sending files in the form
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return direct to success_url

        # render form with errors
        context = self.get_context_data(form=form)
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

Comment: I managed to use your code, which saved the submitted form in the database, but had to make 2 minor changes: first, remove the `self` from `context = super(self).get_context_data(**kwargs)` line, second, remove `pk` from `def post(self, request, pk, **kwargs):` line. Please edit your answer if you confirm these changes so I can accept the answer.

Comment: I have made the edits.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please explain the last two lines of your code? I understood (I think) most of it, but I do not understand what the last two lines do.

Comment: means that form.is_valid() failed, hence re-render the form (which has errors at that point), informing the user of the errors. Make sure to redirect to a success_url in the if block

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a simple FormView:

```
class ContactUsPageView(FormView):

    form_class = ContactForm
    template_name: str = "core/contact-us.html"
    success_url = "..."

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ContactUsPageView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["contact_page_data"] = self.model.objects.filter(key__icontains="تماس")
        return context
```

and display with **{{form}}** your form in html

Comment: What is `success_url`? Is it the message displayed after submitting the form? Must it be on a different template? How can I just display a success message under the form after submitting the form successfully?

Comment: And also, what happened to the `model = SiteDataKeyValue`? Is it ok to eliminate it?

Comment: **success_url** is the url where you want to be redirected after success of form. I do not known anything about **SiteDatKeyValue**, you do not talk about this model, just **ContactUsForm**, so i remove it, there is no sens to keep it, you want to save a ContactUseForm record in db

Comment: My bad, I haven't mentioned that model. It is a model for making templates static data such as the static texts in the differnet pages editable for the admin from panel. I'm using that model for sending a key, value pair to different pages of my templates, as I've mentioned in the docstring in the beginning of the view.